# replacing fragments in android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need help with code snippet for replacing a fragment with another fragment on click of a button.

Here is the XML for the MainActivity
[image]

What can i do to resolve this error?
[image]

Tried searching the web only to come up with the same solution.
If somebody could please help me out on this.

Code for Main.Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    Button button1, button2, button3, button4;
    Fragment fragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.layout2);
        button3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.layout3);
        button4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.layout4);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            fragment = new Fragment2();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frag, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Instead of screenshot please give code snippet so we could read your code clearly. Give your fragment class code and in android-studio put cursor on red underline code and press alt+enter. see what happens

Comment: sure. Just a minute. @Rahul

Comment: It says required android.app.fragment found com.example.user.projectname.fragment

Comment: TRY - com.example.user.projectname.fragment   fgt = new com.example.user.projectname.fragment(). See What happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw few issues in your code:

1. If you add your `fragment` inside xml file, you cant remove/replace it in the future. As described from Google Page:

> Note: When you add a fragment to an activity layout by defining the fragment in the layout XML file, you cannot remove the fragment at runtime. If you plan to swap your fragments in and out during user interaction, you must add the fragment to the activity when the activity first starts, as shown in the next lesson.

2. Your error may come from `casting` fragment. You should check your `Fragment2`. it maybe a support fragment.

**Update**

1. Here's the link to learning more about creating/adding fragment: [Google Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)
2. Based on your comments, you should check what you did import in the `Fragment2` layout (`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` or not). Are all your fragments from the same package or not?

Comment: It says required android.app.fragment found com.example.user.projectname.fragment

Comment: Can you please give me the code example on how to replace the fragment instead of hardcoding it in XML?

Comment: Yes.They are from the same package.

Answer (score 2):

The variable 'fragment' is an object of class Fragment and you are creating it as a object of class Fragment2 (which is  a subclass of Fragment). This is not valid hence it's showing an error. Also to replace any fragment the fragment it should be inside a  container view (usually a FrameLayout) and then you can use the replace transaction to replace it on the button click. The code should be as follows:

XML Code:

```
<FrameLayout
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="frameLayout" />
```

Java Code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout,fragment2).commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: isn't working for me. Can there be any other possible error?

Comment: Yes, in line FragmentManager

Comment: you should use FragmentSupportManager

Comment: yes @SecretCoder is right you may have imported the Fragment(    android.app.Fragment) and not the support Fragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment) so you will need to get the corresponding FragementManager . Try using getFragmentManager() in place of getSupportFragmentManager()

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your `fragment` in your xml with a `FrameLayout`.

Now within button's onClickListener

```
YourFragment fragment = YourFragment.getInstance();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.frLayout, fragment, "TAG");
transaction.commit();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I hoped that too, but I am sorry it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

in xml insted of fragment

and try this

```
Fragment2 frag2 = new Fragment2();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag, frag2);
```

in java code.